# Why is my id failing in my React component?

Tags: reactjs, uuid

I need some help with this code it is giving an error of 'id' not defined, can have some assistance.

```
import React from "react";
    
    const ContactCard = (props) => {
        
        return(
            <div className="item">
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="Header">{props.contact.name}</div>
                    <div>{props.contact.email}</div>
                </div>
                <i className="trash alternate outline icon"
                        style={{color:"red", marginTop: "7px"}}
                    onClick = {() => props.clickHander(id)} >            
                </i>     
            </div>
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] an example of what props looks like coming in?

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, I believe instead of using `id`, use `props.contact.id`. That's why undefined error coming for id.

Answer (score 0):

Going a little further than this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71942628/1952287), While you're bringing in `props` you can also destructure props, example:

```
import React from 'react'

const ContactCard = ({contact, clickHander}) => {
  return (
    <div className='item'>
      <div className='content'>
        <div className='Header'>{contact.name}</div>
        <div>{contact.email}</div>
      </div>
      <i className='trash alternate outline icon' style={{ color: 'red', marginTop: '7px' }} onClick={() => clickHander(contact.id)}></i>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactCard
```